# How to remove the first header line when creating a csv with ogr2ogr?

Tags: grass-gis, ogr2ogr

I use the great approach to large rasters as [described here](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Large_raster_data_processing#Create_a_mosaic)

```
gdaltindex an_index.shp *.tif
ogr2ogr -f CSV list.csv an_index.shp -spat xmin ymin xmax ymax
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list list.csv mosaic.vrt
r.external input=/path/to/mosaic.vrt output=mosaic
```

the resulting list.csv file contains correct paths, but the first line is "location,". It is skipped when vrt file is build, but can I get rid of this line while creating the list.csv?

Grass version is GRASS 7.8.7 (2022)

Comment: Which approach do you try precisely? I don't fully get the problem.

Comment: Sorry, it was a wrong link. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can output CSV to stdout using `/vsistdout/` and remove first line with `sed` or another tool (e.g https://www.baeldung.com/linux/remove-first-line-text-file).

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV /vsistdout/ an_index.shp -spat xmin ymin xmax ymax >| sed '1d' list.csv
```

The other way would be to keep the same command and add one command to clean the CSV file.

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV list.csv an_index.shp -spat xmin ymin xmax ymax
sed -i '1d' list.csv
```